# Login wordpress website using wp-rest api

Tags: php, wordpress, rest, curl, wordpress-theming

I'm using **Wordpress 4.8** and i am new to **rest api**  . I have 2 websites , one is `www.example.com` and second is `www.example.com/site2`. That is second website is installed inside the first .

In example.com I have many users. In site 2 , i have a custom page & in that page i create a custom forms for login . The form is checking the details based on first website users . That is some one enter the login details of first website then they can able to login .
Please check my form

```
<form>
<input type="text" name="user_name" class="user_name" required>
<input type="password" name="user_password" class="user_password" required>
<input tuype="submit" name="submit" class="submit">
</form>

<script>

     $(".submit").on("click",function(){
           var username = $(".user_name").val();
           var password = $(".user_password").val();
            });

</script>
```

Please help to complete this form .Should i need to use `curl` ?  How can i check the login details with the help of rest api

Edit

From my further investigation i am able to do this much code

```
   $(".submit").on("click",function(){
       var username = $(".user_name").val();
       var password = $(".user_password").val();
       var posting = $.post( 'ajax.php', { user1: username, pass1:password } );
           posting.done(function( data ) {
             MYCODE 

             });
    });
```

In ajax.php I write

```
 ini_set('display_errors', 0);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

$username = $_POST["user1"];
$password = $_POST["pass1"];
$headers = array();
//$headers[] = 'Accept: application/json';
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL,"http://www.example.com/wp-json/");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER ,0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('username'=>$username, 'password'=>$password));
$resp = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);

echo $resp;
```

Still no luck.

Comment: you need to use first website user session in second website right? That is not possible. You can login in first website using rest api and can access first website post, page or anything you want but using first website user you cannot do anything in second website.

Comment: no , i just want to check the user is valid user, if user is valid then i need to get his details like email , user id , role etc .

Answer (score 0):

There is many way to login , 
1. cookie based authentication
2. OAuth used
3. Token based Auth

you can use below plugin for token based Auth , https://wordpress.org/plugins/jwt-authentication-for-wp-rest-api/

Comment: Could you please explain.

Comment: install and activate this plugin and follow configuration steps like defined in  plugin home page.